# Why is asking if someone elaborated on a decision, an "Opinion based question"?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, on-topic-definition, opinion-based

This question here:

[Why is/was Bjarne opposed to adding strong/opaque typedefs to the core language of c++?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/432375/why-is-was-bjarne-opposed-to-adding-strong-opaque-typedefs-to-the-core-language)

Is asking if Bjarne ever elaborated on why he opposed strong or opaque typedefs.
It got closed as "Opinion Based". How does that make sense, except in the most narrow interpretation where people **assume** that he has not elaborated on the question at all within the past 5 years, and kept his reasoning completely secret?

Answer (score 3):

One of three things happens with questions like these. One option is it turns into a hunt to find a particular blog post, paper, or book where the person clarifies their stance. Resource requests like this have been determined to be off-topic here. Another option is that the answer hasn't been given anywhere and people guess or share their opinions. A third, but extremely rare option, is that the one person (or in some cases, one of a small group of people) shows up here to answer the question. We expect that questions are answerable by the broader community and not require a specific individual.

I'm not sure that I would have chosen "opinion-based" as the reason for closure. I probably would have gone for the resource request reason. Both are valid, though, since this is likely to become one of the types of questions that we've decided don't belong here.

Comment: `Resource requests like this have been determined to be off-topic here.` -- where exactly?

Comment: @Anon There have been a couple of questions talking about resource requests, but [here is one](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5299/why-are-reference-request-questions-off-topic) that also links to some of the older discussions. The Help Center links to [this more detailed description](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6487#6487).

Comment: I don't see any links to older discussions... and your answer is rather tenuous and truistic and paradoxical. I look at statements like `Questions that simply ask for resources` [Truistic: All questions 'simply' ask for resources] `are not about solving a problem` [Paradoxical] `nor do they allow for answers to be supported by facts or expertise that requires human thought to produce.` [Tenuous: Using search engines requires expertise because often only an expert knows where to look or how to ask a question, and they will readily be more familiar with the forum in which the resources lie]

Comment: @Anon I'm not sure what you are looking for. You asked why your question was closed. I explained. You asked for links to support it, I provided two (both of which also link to other relevant Meta discussions). These are long-standing community norms. If you want to discuss the community standards, make a new Meta question so it's more visible.

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't take the time to look at the latter link yet. Just the former. I'll ruminate on the latter and maybe decide to open something up in meta. Thanks.